# Error Debugging PowerShell Azure Function in VSCode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

New to all of this so sorry if I am just being stupid here. But I installed VSCODE, the Azure Core Functions Ext, PS6, NETCORE2.2, NODEJS.

Setup a Azure Function and go to run with debugging and get the following error message.

[image: Error Message]
.

I can turn the server no problem by going to Terminal -> Run Task -> func: Host Start starting the task but can't debug. What am I missing to get this working?

Yes I see it talks about launch.json but if I have to change it, have zero idea what to put in there.

Comment: Change your interpreter to use ps-core in settings.json.  Presently, it's using Windows PowerShell v5.1.

Comment: I looked in the UI Settings, and scanned the settings.json but found nothing related to interpreter other then something for python. I googled vs code interpreter powershell and came up short there too. I agree though, that seems what needs to be done

Comment: Search integratedterminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be corrected when PowerShell 6.2 is installed. Install powershell 6.2 from [doc](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell) and configure in Visual Studio code as follow.

[image]

Comment: Setting those two fixes it although I had to make the default version: "PowerShell Core 6 (x64)"